# What does ⋀ mean in Isabelle?

Tags: logic, isabelle, quantifiers

(This is pretty much a logic question.) 
 `⋀` such as in `⋀y . Py` seems to be a kind of placeholder. It occurs after using `apply (rule allI)` or `apply (erule exE`. At first I thought it was like a pretend ∀, because of the rule `allI` which is `(!!x. Px) => ∀x. Px` (I believe that `!!` is used to represent `⋀` in the place I got this from). But I didn't seem to be able to apply `allI` in certain scenarios which appeared to match this rule. What does `⋀` really mean? I'm wondering if `⋀` can mean different things in different situations.

Answer (score 3):

`⋀` is an universal quantifier, yes, but it's the *metalogical* one. I.e. the one which you use to describe the logic you work in, including `∀`. Similarly,  is the metalogical implication operator. And these are the only two primitives of Isabelle's metalogic; there is no negation, so it's much weaker than classical logic. See http://isabelle.in.tum.de/coursematerial/PSV2009-1/session2/document.pdf or https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1011/L21/5%20-%20Logic.pdf for more.